# Why can't i change the input file name in php?

Tags: php, html, global-variables

When I run the below code it says

> "Notice: Undefined index: uploadFile in C:\xampp\htdocs\ImageTest\processImage.php on line 17"

But when I replace every instance of uploadFile with fileToUpload it seems to work. Why?

processImage.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title> hello world</title>
</head
<body>
    <?php
        echo ' hi';

        $servername="localhost";
        $username="root";
        $password="";
        $dbname="db_ImageTest";

        $conn=new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

        echo $_FILES["uploadFile"]["name"];

        /*
        echo $image;

        $image_name=$_FILES['image']['name'];
        $image_size=getimagesize($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);

        if($image_size==FALSE){
            echo 'failed';
        }
        $query="INSERT INTO mytable(image, name) VALUES(' {$image}',  '{$image_name}') 
        */
    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

index.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form action="processImage.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    Select image to upload:
    <input type="file" name="uploadFile" />
    <input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit"/>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: As you load html file .. the file in the form is not uploaded and it tries to access thats why it throws warning ,, you can solve `if($_POST) {echo your code here};`

Comment: Can you post the result of a var_dump($_POST, $_FILES);

Comment: echo var_dump($_POST, $_FILES);    gives    array(1) { ["submit"]=> string(12) "Upload Image" } array(1) { ["fileToUpload"]=> array(5) { ["name"]=> string(9) "pupil.png" ["type"]=> string(9) "image/png" ["tmp_name"]=> string(24) "C:\xampp\tmp\phpEC09.tmp" ["error"]=> int(0) ["size"]=> int(585) } }

Answer (score 2):

"Notice: Undefined index: uploadFile in C:\xampp\htdocs\ImageTest\processImage.php on line 17"

It means that file was not sent, you could use `isset` to check if file was attached, otherwise it will throw notice:

```
if (isset($_FILES['uploadFile'])) {
    /** file is there, continue your uploading **/
   }
```

Comment: Yeah, so will isset make uploadFile attached? The weird thing is that when all I change is the variable name, it seems to not be attached anymore.

Comment: It won't, for file upload, you should check does the PHP receives the name you setted, i mean ensure that your HTML file input has the same `name` as you expect in PHP.

Comment: Yeah thats what I was trying to accomplish when I took every uploadFile  and replaced it with fileToUpload; i thought that since it's just a variable name it would still work the same. The error indicates it's not receiving the name. I was following this guide https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp , which uses fileToUpload; I'm not sure why me changing the variable name makes it  not work anymore; there is nothing about the name fileToUpload right??

Comment: Yeah, it doesn't matter what the name is.. Only when there is duplicate name it can cause problems